# C# - Events Question

Tags: c#

Can any C# object be set up such that an event can be tied to it to fire when it's value changes? If so, how is this done? For example, let's take a very simple example. Say I have a variable declared as follows:

```
int i;
```

Is it possible to create an event that fires any time the value of i changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can't change *fields* so that events are fired when the value changes.

On the other hand, you can easily make it so that when a *property* changes, an event is fired. Only the author of the class containing the property can do this, however<sup>1</sup> - you can't attach an event to an arbitrary existing class.

---

<sup>1</sup> A slight exception would be a virtual property, which could be overridden solely for the purpose of raising the event. That would be pretty rare though.

Comment: I need to take a typing class.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface that can be implemented by a class and called by - at least some of - its properties to notify listeners that some values changed.

Comment: + Lots. INotifyPropertyChanged is the standard interface in .NET for this behavior, and it is nearly essential for databinding in WPF and Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the [Observer pattern](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx).

Grz, Kris.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PropertyChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) pattern.